# Django admin list view

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have Model like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, null=False, blank=False)
  field2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Of course it is shown as list like:

```
user1 | field1 | field2
user1 | field1 | field2
user2 | field1 | field2
user2 | field1 | field2
```

I would like to show it like:

```
user1 | field1_count() | field2_count()
user2 | field1_count() | field2_count()
```

I know how to calculate field1_count() and field2_count() for user, but how keep only one row per user?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) attribute to define which fields are displayed in the change list page of the admin.

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'field1_count', 'field2_count')

    def field1_count(self, obj):
        # count field1
        return c

    def field2_count(self, obj):
        # count field2
        return c

 admin.site.register(User, MyAdmin)
```

Note that this will make at least two queries per row in your change list page, which might or might not be a problem in your case.

Alternatively, you can try overwriting either [ModelAdmin.queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset) or [ModelAdmin.changelist_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view).

Comment: Than you for the suggestion, but it is not what I want. I implemented very similar solution, but it is not span lines.